# Issue with stripping all tags except img and a in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, strip-tags

I'm using Wordpress and in my theme's `function.php` I have a function to decode html entities and strip some tags:

```
function entities_and_strip($string, $allowable_tags) {
    $result = html_entity_decode($string)

    return strip_tags($result, $allowable_tags);
}
```

In `single.php` I call this funciton:

```
echo entities_and_strip(get_the_content(), "<img><a>");
```

The problem is it strips `a` tag as well and only allow `img` tag. If I remove `img` from `allowable_tags` then it works.

I noticed two things so far:

1. Passing `<img>` with any other tags (e.g. `strip_tags($string, "<img><ul><li><a>");`) will result in stripping all tags except img.
2. This only happens when I'm in Wordpress environment. I wrote a PHP script with `strip_tag` inside and run it separately. It worked well.

What makes the problem? And how could I solve it?

Comment: How long is your content?  The [PHP manual for strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) says `Tag names within the input HTML that are greater than 1023 bytes in length will be treated as though they are invalid, regardless of the allowable_tags parameter.`

Comment: I think they mention that `Tag "names" that are greater than 1023 bytes` and I don't have such tags.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that as a limit on the input HTML.  I'll get my coat

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this function on my WordPress and it's works, may be there is a problem with the content you are passing to the function , paste the content which you get from the function `get_the_content()`.